# How do I get rid of Word VBA project junk?

Tags: vba, ms-word

When I look at Word VBA on my work computer I have what looks like junk projects. On another PC I have only the normal and currently open documents? Is there a way I can clear this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are either hidden documents belonging to addins you have installed, or they're documents that have ended up in your Word startup folder.

Under file..options..addins, check in "Active Application Add-ins" that you don't have anything you didn't want or know about.

Under file..options..advanced..general..file locations, note down the folder for "Startup". Look in that in Explorer and make sure those TMP files aren't in there (you may have to turn on hidden files).

Chris